# How to compare a two Cursor objects?

Tags: c#, winforms, unit-testing, bitmap

I am creating an unit test and I have a `Cursor` that should be made from a specific `Bitmap`. The `Cursor` is created using the following code:

```
cursor = new Cursor(bmp.GetHicon());
```

where `bmp` is a `Bitmap`.

This always maked the test fail (the handle created by `bmp.GetHicon()` is always new):

```
Assert.AreEqual(bmp.GetHicon(), cursor.Handle);
```

I also thought of using [`Icon.FromHandle`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.drawing.icon.fromhandle).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In fact you are looking for how to compare two cursors.

You have the bitmap and you have a cursor and you want to check if the cursor has been created using the bitmap. To do so, as an option, create a cursor from the bitmap then to compare, save those two cursors (the new one which created from the bitmap and the existing one) into stream and compare the streams.

For example:

```
bool ArEqual(Cursor cur1, Cursor cur2)
{
    byte[] bytes1, bytes2;
    using (var ico = Icon.FromHandle(cur1.Handle))
    using (var fs = new MemoryStream())
    {
        ico.Save(fs);
        bytes1 = fs.ToArray();
    }
    using (var ico = Icon.FromHandle(cur2.Handle))
    using (var fs = new MemoryStream())
    {
        ico.Save(fs);
        bytes2 = fs.ToArray();
    }
    return bytes1.SequenceEqual(bytes2);
}
```